# Generic predicate to implement searching by any string property

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is there possibility to apply searching by any string property of entity? I need to build predicate to use it in LINQ query to database.

```
var stringPropertyNames = typeof(T)
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(pi => pi.PropertyType == typeof(string) && pi.GetGetMethod() != null)
            .Select(pi => pi.Name);

foreach (var item in stringPropertyNames)
{
    // here some code to build Predicate corresponding to sql LIKE statement
}
```

**UPD:**
here is working code:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ContainsInAnyString<T>(IQueryable<T> collection, string query)
{
    var stringPropertyNames = typeof(T)
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(pi => pi.PropertyType == typeof(string) && pi.GetGetMethod() != null)
        .Select(pi => pi.Name);

    var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
    var searchArgument = Expression.Constant(query);
    var method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });

    foreach (var name in stringPropertyNames)
    {
        var currentProp = Expression.Property(item, name);
        var startsWithDishExpr = Expression.Call(currentProp, method, searchArgument);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(startsWithDishExpr, item);
        collection = collection.Where(lambda);
    }

    return collection;
}
```

Hope it would be helpful for someone.

Comment: ok. Could you please show some code how to do it or link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really is rather simple:

```
var entityParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "entity");

return 
 Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
 (
   Expression.Equal
   (
     Expression.MakeMemberAccess(entityParameter, propertyInfo),
     Expression.Constant(valueToSearchBy)
   ),
   entityParameter
 );
```

Of course, this does `A == B`. If you want `A like '%' + B + '%'` instead, you'll have to change the `Expression.Equal` to `string.Contains`. I'll leave that as an excercise, since you haven't shown any of your work yet :)

Comment: thanks for quick reply. It works but when I try to change `Equel` to `string.Contains` get an error. Do you have works example?

Comment: @mykhailovskyi You can't just replace it with a `string.Contains` call - you need to make an *expression* of that call. Have a look at `Expression.Call`. Or, let the compiler do part of your job, and just place the results inside (replacing the arguments, of course).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed your code and did what I need. Put code in text of my question.